# Как спарсить информацию с закрытой страницы

Tags: php, java, html, python

Есть страница на сайте, которая доступна только после того, как ты залогинишься на сайт.

Нужно эту страницу спарсить. Каким образом это можно сделать? То есть сначала что ли как-то залогиниться программно, а потом как спарсить я уже разберусь :)

Языки, которые хочется использовать, это Python или Java (более предпочтительно)
Но если для этого необходим какой-то другой конкретный язык или фреймворк, то изучу, не страшно. Нужна рекомендация, буду благодарен

Comment: Посмотрите, как проходит авторизация на сайте: ctrl+shift+i -> network . Пройдите на страницу авторизации -> авторизуйтесь -> нажмите на первую запись во вкладке network. Посмотрите, что отправляет пользователь (вкладка Form Data), с какими заголовками (request headers) - обратите внимание на строку с куки, она может пригодится, и что отвечает сервер (response headers) - внимание на Set-Cookie - именно некоторые эти куки мы будем использовать в последующих запросах.

Comment: Дальше, напишите функцию авторизации, которая будет отправлять post-запрос для авторизации (на страницу, указанную в поле Referer во всё той же вкладке network'a). Если всё прошло успешно - в ответе программа должна найти и записать (в БД, например) все ключи+значения для Set-Cookie. в последующих запросах просто додавляйте эти куки в хэдер, и будем вам счастье :)
Если в какой-то момент сервер начнёт возвращать ошибки 403 - заново используйте функцию авторизации и обновите значения куки

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Посмотрите, как проходит авторизация на сайте: **ctrl+shift+i** (*chrome*) -> **network** . Пройдите на страницу авторизации -> авторизуйтесь -> нажмите на первую запись во вкладке network.

Посмотрите:

1. что отправляет пользователь (вкладка **Form Data**),
2. с какими заголовками (**request headers**) - обратите внимание на строку с
   куки, она может пригодится
3. и что отвечает сервер (**response
   headers**) - внимание на ***Set-Cookie*** - именно эти куки (или
   какую-то часть из них) программа будет/может использовать в своих запросах. Так же, для аутентификации может быть использован токен - просмотрите тело ответа.

Дальше, напишите ***функцию авторизации***, которая будет отправлять post-запрос для авторизации (*на страницу, указанную в поле Referer во всё той же вкладке network'a*). Если всё прошло успешно - в хэдере ответа сервера программа должна найти и записать (*в БД, например*) все значения для ***Set-Cookie*** или какого-то токена. В последующих запросах просто добавляйте эти куки в хэдер запроса.

Если в какой-то момент сервер начнёт возвращать ошибки 403 - заново используйте функцию авторизации и обновите значения куки

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете посмотреть параметры запроса, отправляемого браузером при логине в консоли браузера. Если этот запрос программно повторить - должны будете получить авторизационные данные. Это может быть `cookie` например, или токен в теле ответа.

Далее нужно через ту же консоль браузера посмотреть какой запрос сайт отправляет на закрытый ресурс. К запросу должны крепиться данные об авторизации. В виде заголовка запроса обычно.

Далее вам нужно повторить этот запрос программно. Язык можно использовать любой, ничего нового и особенного изучать не нужно. Главное - узнать параметры запроса.